# Firestore saves image url and user data only once , how can i resolve this?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-storage

I have 2 methods, the first one stores for cloud storage the other method(Savingtofirestore) saves Item data to firestore and downloads image url .I have a collection called Images and within it i have a document that has an item of the authenticated user .

```
private void uploadImageToStorage() {
    if (filepath != null) {

            // Code for showing progressDialog while uploading
            ProgressDialog progressDialog
                    = new ProgressDialog(AddItem.this);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
            progressDialog.show();

            // Defining the child of storageReference
            StorageReference ref
                    = storageReference
                    .child(
                            "images/"
                                    + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            // adding listeners on upload
            // or failure of image
            ref.putFile(filepath)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(
                            new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(
                                        UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot)
                                {
                                    Task<Uri> uriTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                                    while(!uriTask.isSuccessful());

                                    downloadurl = uriTask.getResult().toString();
                                    if(uriTask.isSuccessful())
                                    {

                                        SavingToFirestore(downloadurl);
                                    }
                                    // Image uploaded successfully
                                    // Dismiss dialog
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    /*Toast
                                            .makeText(AddItem.this,
                                                    "Image Uploaded!!",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                            .show();

                                     */
                                }
                            })

                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e)
                        {

                            // Error, Image not uploaded
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast
                                    .makeText(AddItem.this,
                                            "Failed " + e.getMessage(),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(
                            new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

                                // Progress Listener for loading
                                // percentage on the dialog box
                                @Override
                                public void onProgress(
                                        UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot)
                                {
                                    double progress
                                            = (100.0
                                            * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()
                                            / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                                    progressDialog.setMessage(
                                            "Uploaded "
                                                    + (int)progress + "%");
                                }
                            });
        }
    }
```

private void SavingToFirestore(String url){

// String id = f.getCurrentUser().getUid();

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("users").document(user_id).get()
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                Map<String,String> userMap = new HashMap<>();

                userMap.put("name",name);
                userMap.put("price",price);
                userMap.put("description",description);
                userMap.put("image",downloadurl.toString());
                firebaseFirestore.collection("images").document(user_id).set(userMap)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
             public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) { //if the data is saved successfully return to the main activity
                                itemName.setText("");
                                itemPrice.setText("");
                                itemDescription.setText("");
                                itemImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.itemphoto);
                                Toast.makeText(AddItem.this,"Item Upload successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(AddItem.this,MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(AddItem.this,"Error : "+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
            }
        });


}
```

I am so lost now because i dont not know what am doing wrong ? Maybe i should loop the process?

Comment: exactly what problem you are facing?

Comment: My program stores item data and image url only once when the current user is logged in .

Comment: I want to able to add item data and image url not once , right now its like its overriding what is in firestore

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Hi @AlexMamo  , there is no error but when the currently logged in user is adding items the previously added one is replaced with the new one. Lets say the user adds item 1 successfully when he tries to add item 2 , item 2 replaces item 1 .

Comment: Did Aditya Nandardhane's solution help?

Comment: @AlexMamo it gave an  this is the error ,  >>>>>>>>>>>>> addOnSuccessListener(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener<? super com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference>)' in 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task' cannot be applied to '(anonymous com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener<java.lang.Void>)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, user is adding items the previously added one is replaced with the new one, **It happens because you are using userID as document ID so you need to create separate document every time**.

**You can try something like this-**

```
            Map<String,String> userMap = new HashMap<>();

            userMap.put("userId",user_id);
            userMap.put("name",name);
            userMap.put("price",price);
            userMap.put("description",description);
            userMap.put("image",downloadurl.toString());
            firebaseFirestore.collection("images").add(userMap)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                        @Override
         public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) { //if the data is saved successfully return to the main activity
                            itemName.setText("");
                            itemPrice.setText("");
                            itemDescription.setText("");
                            itemImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.itemphoto);
                            Toast.makeText(AddItem.this,"Item Upload successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(AddItem.this,MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(AddItem.this,"Error : "+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Let me try the suggested solution then i will get back to you.

Comment: This the error i get when i use that >>>>>>>>>>>>  
 'addOnSuccessListener(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener<? super com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference>)' in 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task' cannot be applied to '(anonymous com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener<java.lang.Void>)'

Comment: Thank you Mr Aditya it worked , i handled the error below by changing **new OnSuccessListener<Void>**  to **new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>**, doing this other users wont see the data of other users ,right ?

Comment: great !! @jayCoder

Comment: @jayCoder if the answer was useful for you, you can mark it as useful to reward me. Thanks !!

Comment: I tried @AdityaNandardhane it says my reputation is low